# Configuring Federated login on a .net 6 isolated Azure function App

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-isolated

The are a lot of article out there for configuring federated login with Azure Functions. But most documentation seems to either addres the older (v2) or refer to in-process and not the isolated version of azure functions.

For the isolated functions the easy configuration on the azure function configuration pages is not available.

Is there an example out there or can one be given here on how to configure An .net 6 isolated azure function app with an API to use federated login. Or in other terns how to make [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.User, "get")] work.

Comment: please check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization. You can configure the same in Function app-->Authentication tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to configure an .net 6 isolated azure function app with an API to use federated login or easy configuration

You can setup the easy configuration in .Net 6 isolated function app using below steps-

1. Create an isolated function app and go to Authentication tab

[image]

2. Add an identity provider in the following way

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Once its added, you will see below

[image]

Also you can check, there is an app registered in your Azure AD tenant

[image]

Then I created default isolated function locally and deployed to function app.

Here I have taken authentication level as Anonymous, because **User** option is not yet available in the template while function creation.

[image]

Deployed..

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

When I called the above url in browser, then it got redirected to Azure AD, clicked **Accept**

[image]

[image]

**Reference**-  [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization)

> how to make [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.User, "get")] work.

As per this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#http-auth), Authorization level only have Admin, Function, Anonymous as supported values but I would suggest you to check this with product team to get the latest updates if any.

Comment: That is a very long winded way of saying what you want is still not supported :(. That SO thread you reference is 5 years old!
Not sure if I should mark this as an answer. I appreciate the effort, but the question was how to make AuthorizationLevel.User work. And your last line is basically, you can't...

Comment: I basically have answered the easy configuration/federated login part which is also there in question. I have referred this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#http-auth) too, wherein they have mentioned about supported value of Authorization level. So it would be better if you check this with product team

Comment: It as close an answer I am going to get without the product team getting a move on. So your right. I appreciate the effort you made with the answer and have marked it as answered.

Comment: I was digging deep about it, so you also can get the user information in isolated function. [image](https://i.imgur.com/lMJwMp2.png) redirects to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-user-identities#access-user-claims-in-app-code)